# How to finish every activity on the stack except the first in Android

Tags: android, activity-finish

I'm porting an iPhone app to Android and I can't seem to find a means to pop each activity on the stack except the root activity.

In objective-c I would do something like the below

```
[navController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Anyone know if I can effectively call "finish()" on each activity after some action?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure of what you're asking, but it's definitely safe to call `finish()` on an `Activity` once you're done with it. That will bring you back to whichever activity is before it in the stack.

Comment: finish() will only pop back one level from the navigation stack

Answer (score 40, accepted):

If you want to start one Activity, say, your homescreen, and remove every other Activity in your application's stack, you can use:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); // Removes other Activities from stack
startActivity(intent);
```

If you also want to provide this event in the MainActivity (such as a logo click in the title bar), you can add the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` flag as well to make sure it does not add another instance of itself to the stack.

Comment: it recreates first activity, I mean it calls `onCreate()` of `MainActivity`

Answer (score 3):

Look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP: you can startActivity on the root activity with this flag, and it will blow away all activities above it. You should read the docs carefully about the intent delivery behavior.