# Remove all activities except the first one

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I want to program Home button, so it will remove all `Activities` in stack, except one. I did it like in here: [How to finish every activity on the stack except the first in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6298275/how-to-finish-every-activity-on-the-stack-except-the-first-in-android)

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int itemId = item.getItemId();
    switch (itemId) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AMainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
        startActivity(intent);
        break;
...
```

but this way doesn't suit me, because it removes ALL `Activities` (including the first one) and starts the first one again. For example - if I check user password in `onCreate()`, he would be asked again.
How to remove all `Activities` from stack, but so the first one will not be "touched" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add following property to your AMainActivity's Activity tag in your manifest.xml.

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, according to the documentation of `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`:

> The currently running instance of activity B in the above example will either receive the new intent you are starting here in its onNewIntent() method, **or be itself finished and restarted with the new intent. If it has declared its launch mode to be "multiple" (the default) and you have not set FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP in the same intent, then it will be finished and re-created;** for all other launch modes or if FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP is set then this Intent will be delivered to the current instance's onNewIntent().

So, use additional `Intent` flag:

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

And your activity should not be recreated. Instead, it will just get the new intent delivered via a call to `onNewIntent()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ExcludeFromRecent = "true"` flag in Activities declaration in manifest,  which you don’t want to be in Stack.