# How to finish an activity from a class in android

Tags: android, start-activity, activity-finish

i have three `Activities` A , B  and C ; 
The `Activity` C above the `activity` B and B above A . 
class A :

```
button.setonclicklistener...
.
.
.{
startactivity(A.this , B.class() )  ;
}
.
.
.}
```

class B :

```
button.setonclicklistener...
.
.
.{
startactivity(B.this , C.class() )  ;
}
.
.
.}
```

now I'm in `Activity` C , how `delete` (`finish`)the `Activity` C , and B with a Button From activity C  :

```
button.setonclicklistener...
.
.
.{
Finish();//activity C 
Finish();//activity B 

}
.
.
.}
```

Comment: If you have to do something like this you should probably considering combining B and C into one `Activity` with two `Fragment`s and just switching between the `Fragment`s instead of opening a new `Activity`. Having to finish multiple `Activity`s is in most cases a sign of messed up navigation in your app.

Answer (score 1):

Start Activity C with startActivityForResult.  In ActivityB when onActivityResult is called, call finish.

Answer (score 0):

Start Activity A with flag CLEAR_TOP.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityC.this, ActivityA.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); // Removes other Activities from stack
startActivity(intent);
```

Reference:- 1. [CLEAR_TOP_REFERENCE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)

2. [Answer reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6298329/519718)

Comment: The one problem with this is that the intent of activity A will be overwritten with the new Intent.  This can be a problem if you're depending on values in it

Comment: @GabeSechan it will be weird scenario to have values in Activity A and opening B and C. Anyways that can be handled by saving values in preferences in onPause and loading them back in onResume. No?

Comment: No. The clear top flag erases the original intent. And it's not unusual to have parameters in A that then opens another activity. That said, if A has no parameters clear top is a good solution

Comment: @GabeSechan I see where you are going. Totally agree with your point now. Thanks for sharing your views.